# Using elastic search for a UI dashboard behind a proxy

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-dsl

I am working on a search dashboard with full text search capabilities, backed by ES. The search would initially be consumed by a UI dashboard. I am planning to have an application web service (WS) api layer between the UI dashboard and ES which will route the business search to ES.

There can be multiple clients to WS going forward, each with its own business use cases, and complex data requirements (basically response fields). There are many entities and huge number of fields across them. Each client would need to specify what fields entities it wants to return with what fields.

To support this dynamically changing requirement, one approach could be to have the WS be a pass through to the ES (with pre validations like access control and post transformations to the response from ES). The WS APIs will look exactly like the ES APIs, the UI should build ES queries through JS client and send it to WS, which after access control will get data from ES.

I am new to ES and skeptic of this approach. Can there be any particular challenges in this approach. One of my colleague has worked on ES before but always with a backend Java client, so he's not too sure.

I looked up a ES Js client and there's an official one [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/introduction.html).

Some Context here:

We have around 4 different entities (can increase in future) with both full text and keyword type fields. A typical search could have multiple filters and search terms and would want to specify the result fields. Also, some searches would be across entities and some to individual ones. We are maintaining a separate entity for each entity.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your post is, below is what you want to achieve at high level.

> There can be multiple clients to WS going forward, each with its own
>   business use cases, and complex data requirements (basically response
>   fields)

And as you are not sure, how to do this, you are thinking to build Elasticsearch queries from Javascript in your front-end only. I am not a very big fan of this approach as it exposes, how you are building queries and if some hacker knows crucial like below information, then can bring your entire ES cluster to its knees:

1. Knows what types of wildcard queries.
2. Knows index names and ES cluster details(although you may have access control but still you are exposing the crucial info).
3. How you are building your search queries.

Above are just a few examples and will add more info.

### Right approach

As you already have a backend, where you would be checking the access, there only build the Elasticsearch queries and you even have the advantage of your teammates who knows it.

**For building complex response field, you can use the [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering), using which you can specify in your search request, what all fields you want to return in your search result.**

Comment: That is a nice to have perspective. But other than security, do you foresee any other major challenge. This is an internal application hosted on corp network, so not accessible to outsiders. Also, we'll still restrict complete access but can be open to a large universe of queries. We don't want to code for every other client that wants to use our service. Also source filtering will work at ES, so we need to still provide a way in the WS API for source filtering and translate to ES source filtering. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @mickeymoon, security is a major thing here, but it itself is a major thing, anyway as you mentioned its hosted on corp n/w, u can still live with it, but I don't see a strong  reason to not build the queries in the backend. you don't need to implement the source filtering in your WS API, anyway you will receive what fields you want to filter and include and just pass it to ES query builder, its very simple, if you want I can provide a code sample for it and what your requirements are very common, so dont see a big deal here :)